# How to implement force index on query in cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x, force-index

I am new at CakePHP and want to know how to implement a force index on a query in CakePHP 4.

Anyone can help I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not using auto-quoting (see the `quoteIdentifiers` option in your applications [**datasource configuration**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#configuration)), a simple workaround might do it for you, that is injecting the statements into the `FROM` clause, like:

```php
$query = $Table
    ->find()
    ->from($Table->getTable() . ' FORCE INDEX (foo_idx)');
```

This would generate SQL like

```sql
SELECT ... FROM table_name FORCE INDEX (foo_idx)
```

Once you're using auto-quoting however this will break, as the whole string passed to `from()` will be enclosed in quotes, not just the table name.

If you wanted this to work with auto-quoting, then you'd have to implement your own (extending) driver class, your own query class that has an API to set indices, and finally your own query compiler that compiles those index config accordingly into the proper SQL.

So, no overly straightforward task. Until you've gathered enough experience with the framework to implement and maintain custom logic like this, such cases are often best solved by using custom [**raw SQL queries**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements).